# How to change port for Java Mail on Glassfish/Payara 5

Tags: glassfish-5

I am trying to configure JavaMail Resource on the Admin Console of Glassfish Server 5. I do not know how can change the SMTP port from default 25 to 587. Have checked the Admin Document of the Server but unfortunately there is no mention of setting the SMTP port number.